# Difference between comments shown in YouTube and actual comment list

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am noticing a difference between the number of comments shown in YouTube for a specified Video and the number of comments that actually appear after the comments are loaded.

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aD1VmjGOb_g
This Video shows 21 comments just below the Video description, but if you count the comments it only has 13! The total shown won't get to 21 even if you sum the amount of replies!

Comment: Moreover, the replies count under some comments is higher that the actual number of replies. And even more, for some of your comments, they only show up to yourself, i.e. you're logged in and not for everyone else (check incognito or from other account).

Answer (score 0):

You'll see all 21 comments if you choose the "Newest first" sorting option:
[image]

When using YouTube data API you should use `order: 'time'` when calling the [commentThreads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list)